# how to install\turn on Adobe HTTP Dynamic Streaming Origin Module on an Apache HTTP Server?

Tags: apache, http, dynamic, streaming

how to install\turn on Adobe HTTP Dynamic Streaming Origin Module on an Apache HTTP Server?

Comment: do you mean Flash Media Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - Adobe HTTP Dynamic Streaming is a new alternative to Flash Media Server.
Adobes installation guidelines can be found [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/HTTPStreaming/1.0/Using/WS7b362c044b7dd076-735e76121260080a90e-7ffc.html).